# Sending HTML email through python, bad format

Tags: python, html

I have built an abode XD design, converted it into html code and then put the whole code into text file so I could use a `while open()` function to send it through email. But the problem is that the whole format is not right.

[This is a correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwIJI.png)

[This is a format in email which I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tZiz.png)

```
  EMAIL = f'{login_email}'
    PASSWORD = f'{login_email_pass}'

    message = EmailMessage()
    message['Subject'] = f'{program_name} : {SessionID} Server Launch verification'
    message['From'] = EMAIL
    message['To'] = test_email
    message.set_content('This email is sent using python.')
    #with open('messages.txt', mode = 'r' , encoding= 'UTF-8') as oap:
        #z = oap.read()

    message.add_alternative(f"{z}", subtype = 'html')
```

Comment: Please share your code also.

Comment: Which python or html?

Comment: preferably both. So that it can be reproduced to answer your query.

Comment: HTML code - https://pastebin.com/fYAU5ML6 , I can't put it here because it's too long. Python code I'll put in the question

Comment: Only a subset of HTML is allowed in emails. Does Adobe XD have an export for emails option? You might have an easier time if you use a program that is meant for designing emails.